# How would I sort list items that I am getting from a document library with javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, sharepoint-2013

Currently I have some JavaScript that retrieves list items and displays them as part of an unordered list. I've been given the task of modifying the javascript below to sort items.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
    $.ajax({

        url: "/NewsEvents/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Newsletters')/items?$select=Title,FileRef",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            returnedvalue = data;
            var count = 0;
            $.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {
                $('#NL ul').append("<li>" + "<a href='" + item.FileRef + "'>" + item.Title + "</a>" + "</li>");
                count++;
            });
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }

    });
</script>
```

I haven't done much javascript before and am willing to learn. Would love to be pointed in the right direction rather than just given an answer.

Comment: What is `data.d.results`?

Comment: @JarrodOliver what data are you getting? is it JSON? please share the data that you're getting back

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. My understanding would be that it is the list of items returned from url:"/NewsEvents........."

Comment: @HenryDev an example dataset returned is this. http://imgur.com/a/ijSEu

Each of which are hyperlinks to the relevant posts in the Newsletters list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that `data.d.results` is a JavaScript array that resembles the following example:

```
results: [
    {
        Title: "Article Title",
        FileRef: "something/or/other"
    },
    {
        Title: "Another Article Title",
        FileRef: "something/or/other/again"
    },
]
```

JavaScript's `Array` type has a built-in `sort` method, which accepts a custom comparator ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort ).

I use the `localeCompare` ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare ) method to compare the `Title` values of each array element.

I specify `sensitivity: "base"` to perform a case and and accent invariant comparison, so "article" and "Article" are considered equal when compared.

```
success: function( data ) {

    data.d.results.sort(
        function( left, right ) {
            return left.Title.localeCompare( right.Title, { sensitivity: "base" } );
        }
    );

    // rest of your code here
}
```

Comment: I believe you are right in saying that results is an array with titles and references to files. I'll try adding a sort.

Thanks.

EDIT: Why do you use left.() and right.()?

Comment: @JarrodOliver Given the comparator accepts two parameters, what would you call them?

Comment: I understand now. It's part of the sort() method. Looking at the code I posted in OP, do you understand what the point of 'Index' is in:
$.each(data.d.dresults,function(index,item)?

Edit:Removing it still displays x amount of items but the titles appear to be all 'undefined'. I can't see any reference to index whatsoever?

Comment: @JarrodOliver It's a parameter that jQuery expects. It's not used in your case, but it contains the index in the array of the item currently in-scope.

Comment: Thanks gotcha. I haven't managed to get the sort to work correctly yet but I'll get there. If I sort the way you have, will data.d.results be sorted whenever I refer to it?

EDIT: IT works thankyou so much!